# How can I tell if a civilian is a Faceless?

Tags: xcom-2

Faceless are dangerous to deal with, moreso when they are concealed as civilians. An outcome of a Dark Event is to have Faceless in missions as civilians, and it's known that even "fleeing" civilians can be Faceless.  How do I detect these guys before its too late for my squad?

Comment: There's always the option to just end every one of the visible ADVENT buggers, Faceless will reveal themselves if there are no other enemies left

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Some tricks I've learned so far:

- Battle Scanners (can be built after ADVENT Trooper Autopsy) deployed in range of civilians will reveal a Faceless if they are one (and will force them to transform)
- Specialist ability 'Scanning Protocol' will allow you to scan an area an reveal enemies and Faceless
- Firing grenades at a civilian works as well; if you fire at one and DO NOT receive a Friendly Fire warning, it's safe to say the civilian is a Faceless unit (real civilians will always trigger a friendly fire warning)

  - Sidenote on firing grenades. When the FF warning comes up you have a choice to cancel your shot. If you don't get it, you will fire a grenade.  Watch out if you are on Ironman as all actions are final.
- On civilian rescue missions, ADVENT troops will kill civilians every turn. Civilians cannot take more than 3 damage or they will die. However, ADVENT AI will sometimes shoot a civilian that does not die (meaning it is a Faceless unit).
- Faceless units will automatically reveal themselves if no other enemy troops are alive (ADVENT, sneks, robos, mutons, etc.)

Comment: With "battle scanners" do you mean the "scan protocol" of the specialist class or is that some utility item I haven't unlocked yet? Regarding scanning civilians with grenades: Do you get the warning before throwing the grenade or afterwards? I would rather prefer to avoid wasting grenades and injuring civilians.

Comment: @Philipp Battle Scanners are deployables you can build after completing an ADVENT Trooper autopsy. It's like the Battle Scanner from XCOM:EU, you deploy it, it has a range and it detects enemies in hiding or concealed by fog of war

Comment: I've never seen a Faceless getting shot by ADVENT. Has this possibly been patched?

Answer (score 10):

If a civilian is on fire, but still alive, it's a Faceless.  Civilians have few enough health that they can't survive being on fire.  I suspect the same is true of a civilian that's fallen from a height, but I'm not sure about that one.

Comment: I've never heard of this game before today but this answer makes me very interested....

Comment: Are you suggesting putting all civilians on fire? ahahah

Comment: @J.C.Leitão No one said it wasn't a *flawed* approach, just that its results were accurate. ;)

Comment: Time for a spy check?

Answer (score 6):

IME it's generally pretty simple to tell: you don't know the difference, but the aliens do!  If you see a civilian surrounded by active, heavily-armed aliens, and they haven't shot him yet despite having had plenty of turns to do so, shoot him yourself because he's one of theirs.  (By "active" I mean that you've discovered a group of aliens in the area and they've done their silly "war cry and then run for cover" thing.  If they have a "civilian" in their midst, he's almost certainly not a civilian.)

So far, I've never had one of the "low-hanging fruit" (the civilians that start off right by your starting point with no real chance of the aliens reaching them before you do) be a Faceless.  Not sure if that's just luck or if it's deliberately set up that way, though.

Comment: Sometimes, for ex on civilian rescue missions, you get 5 civilians all clustered together, with a few faceless civs thrown in so it's not so "obvious" which one's which

Comment: I had a "low hanging fruit" turn out to be a faceless today.

Answer (score 0):

Another strategy I use is to approach the civilian. If the civilian is a faceless it will always reveal. At least I've never seen one to not reveal upon me approaching.

Now of course this is risky business and if you are not close enough with a soldier to approach the civilian from the first move then you're in for a treat.

That's why I almost always use a ranger that has both Run&Gun and Implacable. I kill the faceless with a good shotgun and retreat :)